# Silverstripe 3 - GridFieldExtensions MultiClass Adding

Tags: silverstripe

I'm trying to use https://github.com/silverstripe-australia/silverstripe-gridfieldextensions/ to create a gridfield where I can add different types of dataobjects.

Sadly I can't figure out how to write the correct code for that on my class where I want the gridfield.

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

**UPDATE:**
Based on your answers, I now have the following structure

```
class ModularPage extends Page {

   private static $has_many = array(
    'Sections' => 'MP_Section',
    'Galleries' => 'MP_Gallery',
    'Paragraphs' => 'MP_Paragraph'
    );

    public function getCMSFields() {
        ...

        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', $mutli_grid = GridField::create('Sections', 'Sektionen', $this->Sections(), MultiClassGrid::create(15)));

        ...
    }

}

class MP_Section extends DataObject {

    private static $has_one = array(
        'Section' => 'MP_Section',
        'ModularPage' => 'ModularPage'
    );

}

class MP_Gallery extends MP_Section {

    private static $has_one = array(
        'Section' => 'MP_Section',
        'ModularPage' => 'ModularPage'
    );

}
```

So far, so good? Is this right until now?

Cause If I want to add for example a gallery, I receive the following error

> [User Error] Couldn't run query: SELECT DISTINCT "MP_Section"."ID", "MP_Section"."SortID" FROM "MP_Section" LEFT JOIN "MP_Gallery" ON "MP_Gallery"."ID" = "MP_Section"."ID" LEFT JOIN "MP_Paragraph" ON "MP_Paragraph"."ID" = "MP_Section"."ID" WHERE ("ModularPageID" = '13') ORDER BY "MP_Section"."SortID" ASC LIMIT 9223372036854775807 Column 'ModularPageID' in where clause is ambiguous

Comment: What's a `MultiClassGrid`? Why does all your DataObjects have the same has_one definition? Only `MP_Section` should have `'ModularPage' => 'ModularPage'` and that's it? And on the page you probably just really need `'Sections' => 'MP_Section'` in the has_many and that's it...

Comment: Thank you, the useless $has_one relations were a stupid mistake. MultiClassGrid is a class that extends 'GridFieldConfig' so that I can reuse the same config

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how I usually setup my `GridField`:

```
$c = GridFieldConfig_RelationEditor::create();
$c->removeComponentsByType('GridFieldAddNewButton')
  ->addComponent(new GridFieldAddNewMultiClass())
  ;

$c->getComponentByType('GridFieldAddNewMultiClass')
  ->setClasses(array(
    'SectionThemesBlock'    => SectionThemesBlock::get_section_type(),
    'SectionFeaturedCourse' => SectionFeaturedCourse::get_section_type(),
    'SectionCallForAction'  => SectionCallForAction::get_section_type(),
    'SectionContactSheet'   => SectionContactSheet::get_section_type()
    //....
  ));

$f = GridField::create('Sections', "Sections", $this->Sections(), $c);
$fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Sections", $f);
```

Based on the `GridFieldConfig_RelationEditor`, just remove `GridFieldAddNewButton` then add `GridFieldAddNewMultiClass`. Then configure the component to know which classes to have available in the dropdown to create. All those `SectionThemesBlock`, `SectionFeaturedCourse` etc extend a common `Section` dataObject as base. The `get_section_type()` function is a custom static function on the `Section` dataobject to get a nice looking name in the dropdown and not have to type it manually all the time....

The basics of the `Section` dataobject looks like so:

```
class Section extends DataObject {

  public static function get_section_type()
  {
    return trim(preg_replace('/([A-Z])/', ' $1', str_ireplace('Section', '', get_called_class())));
  }

  //...
}
```

And the page where that gridField goes and that has the relation defined on:

```
class Page extends SiteTree {
  //...
  private static $has_many = array(
    'Slides' => 'Slide'
  );
  //...
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. I used this and updated my question.

Comment: I've added the Page class in the answer above. Most likely, you issue comes from how you defined your relations. You should have just one like `'Sections' => 'MP_Section'`

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work

```
        $config = new GridFieldConfig_RecordEditor();
        $config->addComponent(new GridFieldAddNewMultiClass());
         ...
        $grid = GridField::create('Grid', 'Grid', $this->GalleryItems(), $config);
```

You need three DataObjects:

- `GalleryItem extends DataObject{}`
- `FooGalleryItem extends GalleryItem{}`
- `BarGalleryItem extends GalleryItem{}`